# Add custom css rule with angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to make an application with dynamic theming. For example, there is a button, you click it and color of some elements changes by some rule. First idea - do it with

```
<style type="text/css" ng-bind="ownStyle"></style>
```

and init ownStyle in $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.ownStyle = "* {color: green }";
```

But it seems awful + it's too hard to write css rules as string. Is there a more elegancy way to do it?

Comment: It could be possible to simply have the rules in your own CSS file, but preface them all with a particular class (eg `.ownStyle .myThing`). Then, to turn it on, add that class to a containing element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can try something like this..

```js
$rootScope.color = red;

$scope.changecolor = function(){
  $rootScope.color = blue;  
}
```

```css
/* Base color */
.dinamic{
  background-color: white;  
}
```

```html
<style>
  .dinamic{
    background-color: {{$rootScope.color}} !important;
  }
</style>

<button class="dinamic">I Will Change Color</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this solution is better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

Just add this directive to "some elements", set proper condition and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class built in directive.

```
<div ng-class="{'some-class': condition}></div>
```